# COM object to web service for mobile devices

Tags: iphone, soap, service

We got a COM object for our web applications. now we need to develop application for different mobile devices like IPhone, Android and windows mobile. what are the options out there ( rest server, soap serverice ) any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly recommend sticking with a REST service using JSON or a very simple XML for mobile delivery due to the bandwidth considerations for mobile networks.  SOAP is too expensive a protocol for efficient mobile data transfer.  In the case of iPhone, you will be hard pressed to find a SOAP library available.